# How to Write Code Using Ternary operator?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, optimization, ternary-operator

```
func checkBtn () {
      //  btnDone.isEnabled = self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0 ? true : false
    if self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0 {
        btnDone.isEnabled = true
    }
    else {
        if arrEmployeeCount?.count > 0 {
             btnDone.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            btnDone.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

how to write this code using ternary operator or in more optimised way ?

Comment: It is perfect, what is the issue in it?

Comment: i only see a formatting issue, which is dropping the else blocks onto a lower line

Comment: `Ternary operator != Optimised Code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this:

```
btnDone.isEnabled = contactSelectViewList.count > 0 || (arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0) > 0
```

**EXPLANATION**

Since you are conditionally setting `isEnabled` to a Boolean value, you can use that exact condition to set the value to drop if/else statements, or ternary operators. In other words, if you are using:

```
if self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0 {
    btnDone.isEnabled = true
}
```

Then you are basically saying: if `self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0` is `true`, then set `btnDone.isEnabled` to `true`.

Therefore you can easily refactor the code to get the same result by rewriting it to:

```
btnDone.isEnabled = self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0
```

Because if `self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0` is true, then it will be evaluated as

```
btnDone.isEnabled = true
```

otherwise it would be evaluated as:

```
btnDone.isEnabled = false
```

Now your case is a bit more complex, because you have two conditions. But by reading your code we can tell that what you want to is to enabled the button when at least on of those two arrays has count > 0. Therefore we just change the condition to `contactSelectViewList.count > 0` OR `(arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0) > 0`. Again, the rest is the same.

The `??` operator works with optionals to provide a default value when the left-hand side is nil. Thus if `arrEmployeeCount?.count` evaluates to nil, `arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0` will be evaluated to `0`, since we provided that as a default value (I assume that if there is no `arrEmployeeCount` you want to treat it as if there was one, but empty.

**So a solution you might want to have is this:**

```
btnDone.isEnabled = contactSelectViewList.count > 0 || (arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0) > 0
```

Button is enabled when either of the arrays is not empty. You might even consider refactoring it using `isEmpty` for potentially better readability:

```
btnDone.isEnabled = !contactSelectViewList.isEmpty || !(arrEmployeeCount ?? []).isEmpty
```

(`arrEmployeeCount ?? []` will provide an empty array if `arrEmployeeCount` is `nil`)

Answer (score 1):

you can combine condition other then no optimisation possible.

*Suggestion is not use Ternary operator in such  a condition will make your code hard to read.*

```
if self.contactSelectViewList.count > 0  || arrEmployeeCount?.count > 0 {
    btnDone.isEnabled = true
} else {
    btnDone.isEnabled = false

}
```

Or Better solution, automatically enable disable button on change of count

```
var contactSelectViewList = [Int]()  {
    didSet {
        if !contactSelectViewList.isEmpty ||  (arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0) > 0  {
            btnDone.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            btnDone.isEnabled = false

        }
    }
}

var arrEmployeeCount : [Int]? {
    didSet {
        if !contactSelectViewList.isEmpty ||  (arrEmployeeCount?.count ?? 0) > 0  {
            btnDone.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            btnDone.isEnabled = false

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your example you can do like this with `ternary(?)` operator.

```
btnDone.isEnabled = contactSelectViewList.count > 0 ? true : (arrEmployeeCount.count > 0 ? true : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me also add one option:

```
let isEnabled = (self.contactSelectViewList.count + arrEmployeeCount?.count) > 0
btnDone.isEnabled = isEnabled
```